# Regex optionally match port number in url

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a regex like `http:\/\/(?<Servername>[^"]+):(?<Port>[^"]+)` to pick server and port from a url. This works fine when port exists in the url but when port number doesn't exist it doesn't match server either.
For example,

```
Url -> http://Server1:20 
Values Returned ServerName = Server1 Port = 20
Url ->    http://Server2 
Values Returned ServerName = blank Port = blank
```

For the second case I would like to get values ServerName = Server2 Port = blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the regex a bit as

```
^http:\/\/(?<Servername>[^:]+)(:(?<Port>.+))?$
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/sN8iT4/1

**Changes made**

- `[^:]+` matches anything other than `:`. This part matches the `Servername`
- `(:(?<Port>.+))?` matches anything followed by `:`. This part matches the `Portnumber`

  - `?` quantifier, quantifies zero or one occurence of Portnumber

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for the case when both server and port exist in the url.

Comment: @Nadeem which language are you using?

Comment: I am using powershell

Comment: @Nadeem It does work in the regex101, is your string same as the input provided?

Comment: This is good working regex +1. It should work in any regex tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\/\/)([^:]+):?(.*)
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/44